# C/C++ Code navigation not working in vscode remote development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Tried to access a remote project (from Linux environment) over vscode remote development environment, followed all the necessary steps mentioned in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview, Able to see the files and folder structure but unable to navigate the source code. Tried "Goto Definition"(F12) and Ctrl+ Click also not working

Tried to set max watch value to fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 still issue remain same

Answer (score 0):

Once I reload the extensions it worked fine. I installed C/C++ IntelliSense from Microsoft and Austin

Comment: which extension did you reload?

Comment: @Sajib I believe it is the IntelliSense extension